# Get The First Event From More Than One Generator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I have three generators. Each one yields results/events in chronological order.
What I want to be able to do is figure out which of the three generators has the next (chronological) event. 
One way that I though of is to have a list of one event from each generator, and which generator it came from. Then, sort the list, take the first event, and add the next event from the corresponding generator to my list.
Is there a better/more efficient/standard way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: can you make an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not give a concrete example I can only provide some ideas/pseudocode for you. The idea is to hold at most `n` items from `n` iterators in memory since each iterator yields chronologically sorted objects. Also inserting into/getting from a `PriorityQueue` will be faster than sorting a list over and over again.

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue

def yield_chronologically(iterators):
    'iterators: list of iterator objects'
    PQ = PriorityQueue()

    # put first n items
    for i, it in enumerate(iterators):
        try:
            nxt = next(it)            
            # this is where you have to determine the priority
            # with a function get_chronological_key you have yet to write
            chronological_key = get_chronological_key(nxt) 
            PQ.put(chronological_key, (i, nxt))
        except StopIteration:
            pass

    # yield items and insert next item from iterator that was taken from
    # into the PQ
    while not PQ.empty():
        _, (i, nxt) = PQ.get()
        yield nxt
        try:
            nxt = next(iterators[i])                
            chronological_key = get_chronological_key(nxt)
            PQ.put(chronological_key, (i, nxt))
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured that there had to be a "standard" way of dealing with this.

Comment: @GreeTreePython no problem. In order to make the function more general, you could define it to take a second argument `key_function` which is the function that is applied to the objects yielded by the iterators in order to determine the priority queue insertion point. I.e. `key = key_function(nxt)`.